# How do you kill a task only if exists msbuild

Tags: msbuild

need to kill a task in msbuild but only if this task is running .

How do you do that?

Given I have something like below,how do I modify to kill the process only if running?

```
    <!-- List of processes to kill -->
    <ItemGroup>
    <Process Include="Process1.exe" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name = "Kill">
    <Exec Command="taskkill /F /IM %(Process.Identity)" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
    </Target>
    </Project>
```

Many thanks

Comment: There might be solutions that don't include a custom task, but I would suggest [using one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/662005/21567). Apart from that, why bother? Your `Exec`, as you have it, doesn't do anything if the process in question doesn't exist.

Comment: Are u saying that sample I loaded already does what I want? If that is the case it doesn't work

Comment: Also add `IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true"` to the `Exec` element.

Comment: Thanks for your time FYI I get error 128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'll make this an answer, because it isn't a good fit for the comments (any more).

Here is what works for me, in that it doesn't cause MSBuild to end with an error, if the process in question does not exist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Kill"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!-- List of processes to kill -->
    <ItemGroup>
    <Process Include="Process1.exe" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name = "Kill">
        <Exec Command="taskkill /F /IM %(Process.Identity)" 
              IgnoreExitCode="true"
              IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Here's the output:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 20.07.2017 16:17:57.
Project "D:\Sources\MarGe\marge\Main\foo.proj" on node 1 (Kill target(s)).
Kill:
  taskkill /F /IM Process1.exe
  ERROR: The process "Process1.exe" not found.
  The command "taskkill /F /IM Process1.exe" exited with code 128.
Done Building Project "D:\Sources\MarGe\marge\Main\foo.proj" (Kill target(s)).


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

And yes, the actual `taskkill.exe` command "fails" with error 128, after all the process does not exist. However, it doesn't cause your build to fail. That is,
it is for informational purposes only.

If you have other targets depending on the `Kill` target they will run.

Of course that also means, that you have no way to figure out if the `Kill` target did actually successfully kill the process in question, should it exist.
Because in that case the error would also be ignored.

If you can live with that, there is no need to determine if the process exists, before attempting to kill it.

Note that there is race condition there anywhere. Assume you write some code to check if the process exists, before killing it. That code would tell you "yes, the process exists", but by the time the actual `taskkill` executes the process might have terminated (by itself or being killed by someone else). So in the end you have to live with failures of `taskkill` anyway.

So, to deal with that it is best to evaluate the exit code of the `taskkill` command in MSBuild and behave accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Kill"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!-- List of processes to kill -->
    <ItemGroup>
    <Process Include="process1.exe" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name = "Kill">
        <Exec Command="taskkill /F /IM %(Process.Identity)" 
              IgnoreExitCode="true"
              IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true">
              <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode"/>
        </Exec>
        <Error Text="Cannot kill process." Condition="$(ErrorCode) == 1"/>
        <Message Text="Process does not exist." Condition="$(ErrorCode) == 128"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

The common (possible?) exit codes of `taskkill` seem to be:

- 0 success
- 1 process exists, but failed to kill (e.g. permission issue)
- 128 process does not exist

(See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11099871/21567) for a related topic.)

Comment: Wow let me digest it

Comment: Your explanation is really good however our Internal build still fails. I guess there is no way to turn this as success then?

Comment: Well, you'd have to provide more information about the actual error and your build system. Consider asking a new question with more (detailed) information.

Comment: I am happy and grateful with your answer thanks for your time

Comment: Not sure why, but when inserting your snippe in my VS .csproj, I do not get these messages displayed. All I get is: ERROR: The process "VSCompiler.exe" not found. Any idea why it does not display: "Process does not exist"

Comment: @progLearner Well, because it does not? No seriously, how do you know that VSCompiler.exe should even exist at the point in time you think it does? A process not existing is a legitimate result of attempting to kill it, thus `taskkill` shows this message.